# format html in ckeditor if text is in not correct format

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x, freetextbox

I have an old ASP.NET application that uses freetextbox WYSIWYG editor. But it saves a weird html (not particular format of html)into database.

```
&lt;TABLE class=mceVisualAid border=0 width=560 align=center height=395&gt;
&lt;TBODY&gt;
&lt;TR align=center&gt;
&lt;TD class=mceVisualAid&gt;&lt;SPAN&gt;
&lt;H1 style=COLOR: rgb(0,0,0)    align=center&gt;&lt;SPAN&gt;&lt;SPAN&gt;&lt;SPAN&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;FONT size=3&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;FONT size=3&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;FONT size=2&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;FONT size=3&gt; Message&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;/SPAN&gt;&lt;/SPAN&gt;&lt;/SPAN&gt;&lt;/H1&gt;
&lt;H1 style=COLOR: rgb(0,0,0) align=center&gt;&lt;SPAN&gt;&lt;SPAN&gt;&lt;SPAN&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;FONT size=3&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;FONT size=3&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;FONT size=2&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;&lt;FONT size=3&gt;16 August 2013&lt;/FONT&gt;
```

Now I'm using ckeditor WYSIWYG in as ASP.net MVC application which uses same data that is saved in databse but i'm not getting a perfect way to render that html into editor. My config.js of ckeditor is :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
config.entities = false;
config.basicEntities = false;
config.entities_greek = false;
config.entities_latin = false;

};
```

While rendering it shows like:
[image]

Comment: need to decode htmlentities .. easy to search

Comment: In html it is just a textarea and in js called $('#MyId).ckeditor()

Comment: fine...that html editor expects html so you need to decode the `htmlentities`. Otherwise they appear as text which is exactly what you are seeing

Comment: I tried to convert it into html entities like &lt; to < but this also didn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried something like this in the View: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.MyContent));

Comment: @J.Olsson Thanks Olsson your suggestion worked I have changed it like
Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Message)).ToHtmlString().
Please put it in answer.

Comment: @SundarSingh I've put it in an answer. Just make sure to run a anti-XSS sanitizer if you will use this in a production enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in the View:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.MyContent)).ToHtmlString();
```

---

Just verify the input in the CKEditor checks for XSS och illegal tags.

One way to do this is using a external anti-XSS library and before save to the database you should run it trough the sanitizer. The important thing is to do it on the Server-side.

Below is just a suggestion on a anti-XSS library (don't know if there is something better since i used this a long time ago)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx

Answer (score 0):

These are htmlentities. You need to convert these symbols to real characters.

One popular way to do this in JS is:

```
var htmlEntities = $('#MyId').ckeditor();   //Or whatever the way you read data 
var pureHtml = $('<textarea />').html(htmlEntities).text();  //Convert
```

Or the following cleaner way:

```
function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
      // strip script/html tags
      str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
      str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
      element.innerHTML = str;
      str = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }

    return str;
  }
```